# How Multi-threaded program works in C?

Tags: c, multithreading, operating-system

I am a complete newbie and I have been coding producer-consumer problem with fixed buffer size what I observed for buffer-size 1 is very different from what I expected. I print "x-->" when I produce x and "-->x" when x is consumed.
The output I get is like this: \

```
0 --->
1 --->
2 --->
---> 0
---> 1
---> 2
3 --->
4 --->
5 --->
---> 3
---> 4
---> 5
```

I am confused about how 1,2,3 reproduced at once and then 1,2,3 consumed at once can someone explain, please.

Here is my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define BUFFER_SIZE 1
#define OVER (-1)


int filled = 0;

struct prodcons {
    int buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];      /* the actual data */
    pthread_mutex_t lock;         /* mutex ensuring exclusive access to buffer */
    int readpos, writepos;        /* positions for reading and writing */
    pthread_cond_t notempty;      /* signaled when buffer is not empty */
    pthread_cond_t notfull;       /* signaled when buffer is not full */
};

void init(struct prodcons * b)
{
    pthread_mutex_init(&b->lock, NULL);
    pthread_cond_init(&b->notempty, NULL);
    pthread_cond_init(&b->notfull, NULL);
    b->readpos = 0;
    b->writepos = 0;
}

void put(struct prodcons * b, int data)
{
    pthread_mutex_lock(&b->lock);
    if(BUFFER_SIZE == 1) {
        if(filled) {
            pthread_cond_wait(&b->notfull, &b->lock);
        }
        b->buffer[0] = data;
        filled = 1;
    }
    else {
        /* Wait until buffer is not full */
        while ((b->writepos + 1) % BUFFER_SIZE == b->readpos) {
            pthread_cond_wait(&b->notfull, &b->lock);
            /* pthread_cond_wait reacquired b->lock before returning */
        }
        /* Write the data and advance write pointer */
        b->buffer[b->writepos] = data;
        b->writepos++;
        if (b->writepos >= BUFFER_SIZE) b->writepos = 0;
        /* Signal that the buffer is now not empty */
    }

    pthread_cond_signal(&b->notempty);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&b->lock);
}

int get(struct prodcons * b)
{
    int data = 0;
    pthread_mutex_lock(&b->lock);
    if(BUFFER_SIZE == 1) {
        if(!filled) {
            pthread_cond_wait(&b->notempty, &b->lock);
        }
        data = b->buffer[0];
        filled = 0;
    }
    else {
        /* Wait until buffer is not empty */
        while (b->writepos == b->readpos) {
            pthread_cond_wait(&b->notempty, &b->lock);
        }
        /* Read the data and advance read pointer */
        data = b->buffer[b->readpos];
        b->readpos++;
        if (b->readpos >= BUFFER_SIZE) b->readpos = 0;
        /* Signal that the buffer is now not full */
    }
    pthread_cond_signal(&b->notfull);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&b->lock);
    return data;
}

struct prodcons buffer;

void * producer(void * data)
{
    int n;
    for (n = 0; n < 10000; n++) {
        printf("%d --->\n", n);
        put(&buffer, n);
    }
    put(&buffer, OVER);
    return NULL;
}

void * consumer(void * data)
{
    int d;
    while (1) {
        d = get(&buffer);
        if (d == OVER) break;
        printf("---> %d\n", d);
    }
    return NULL;
}
int main(void)
{
    pthread_t th_a, th_b;
    void * retval;
    init(&buffer);
    /* Create the threads */
    pthread_create(&th_a, NULL, producer, 0);
    pthread_create(&th_b, NULL, consumer, 0);
    /* Wait until producer and consumer finish. */
    pthread_join(th_a, &retval);
    pthread_join(th_b, &retval);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "at once"? Perhaps it would be clearer if you also described what you expect the output to be like.

Comment: It may be simply buffering in the log output. To check, change `printf("...")` to `fprintf(stderr, "...")`. The standard error output stream is designed to avoid buffering, so error messages show up immediately.

Comment: You forgot to use [fflush(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fflush.3.html) in your code, and you could use [usleep(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/usleep.3.html) to slow it down

Comment: but "at once" I mean how can more than 1 items get produced consecutively without any item being consumed in between in a buffer with a buffer size of 1(this was just an illusion created by the printf statements an is not really it happening). Yeah but I realized that print() statements are out of critical section so they might not be synchronized. The expected answer was that of Answer of @Erdal Küçük

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output is not guaranteed as you expect it. I implemented a timestamp, which shows, when the `put` and `get` methods are called (time is relative to when `init` was called):

```
[ 44491 ns] 0 --->
[115427 ns] 1 --->
[153189 ns] ---> 0
[178376 ns] 2 --->
[182891 ns] 3 --->
[183518 ns] ---> 1
[188542 ns] ---> 2
[198661 ns] 4 --->
[203461 ns] ---> 3
[206636 ns] ---> 4
[204180 ns] 5 --->
[212146 ns] 6 --->
[221019 ns] ---> 5
[224146 ns] ---> 6
[221877 ns] 7 --->
[230976 ns] 8 --->
[232130 ns] 9 --->
[232347 ns] ---> 7
[237920 ns] ---> 8
[239051 ns] ---> 9
[239312 ns] 10 --->
[244770 ns] 11 --->
[245918 ns] 12 --->
[246106 ns] ---> 10
...
```

You should know, that `stdout` is shared by the two threads, so how the locking is implemented there, who knows.

If you want synchronized output, you have to put `printf` into the synchronized sections (after accessing your buffer in the `put` and `get` methods).

Then you get the output:

```
[ 31900 ns] 0 --->
[ 77228 ns] ---> 0
[ 85722 ns] 1 --->
[ 90959 ns] ---> 1
[ 95490 ns] 2 --->
[ 99591 ns] ---> 2
[103447 ns] 3 --->
[107385 ns] ---> 3
[111325 ns] 4 --->
[115215 ns] ---> 4
[119143 ns] 5 --->
[123066 ns] ---> 5
[126962 ns] 6 --->
[130860 ns] ---> 6
[134561 ns] 7 --->
[138427 ns] ---> 7
[142188 ns] 8 --->
[146115 ns] ---> 8
[149797 ns] 9 --->
[153534 ns] ---> 9
[157856 ns] 10 --->
[161631 ns] ---> 10
...
```